# UITextField not editable in modal window

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UITextField in a modal window that I open with UIModalPresentationFormSheet.  The UITextField is Enabled, UserInteraction is Enabled, and a referencing outlet is set up in my class.

When I click on the UITextField, the keyboard pops up, but when I type on the keyboard, the UITextField does not change.  I print the UITextField's .text when I close the modal screen, and it is null.

Can you edit UITextFields in a modal window?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this John? I am currently having the same issue.

Comment: I am having this problem now as well...